# how to create custom tree model WITHOUT mat-tree in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a tree structure like below :
[image]

every item can have unlimited nested children. I created it like below but it only shows the parent and their children. It doesn't show the children of their children(only shows 2 level). This is the html code:

```
 <div *ngFor="let parent of phonebookTreeModelArray; let i = index">
      <div
        class="tree-parent"
        (mouseenter)="showButtons(i)"
        (mouseleave)="hideButtons(i)"
      >
        <p class="phonebook-title" (click)="displayChilds(i)">
          {{ parent.name }}
        </p>
        
      </div>
      <div
        class="tree-children"
        *ngIf="parent.children.length > 0 && currentDisplayChildIndex === i"
      >
        <div class="tree-child" *ngFor="let child of parent.children">
          <p class="phonebook-title">
            {{ child.name }}
          </p>
         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I don't know how to implement it when the nested tree is infinite.

Comment: You could create a custom component that handle the root level of a dataSource and that calls itself in a recursive way.

Comment: See, e.g this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305905/how-can-i-create-a-nested-recursive-table-that-can-drill-down-x-levels-in-angul/55315414#55315414) or this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812), or this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905207/angular-8-implementing-a-hierarchical-list-recursively-with-dynamic-expansion/61911633#61911633)