# How to insert specific component in DOM by reference in Angular2

Tags: angular

I want to write a small tool that runs in browser.
For that I would like to have a tree view with roots and children, there being dynamically many roots and each root having dynamically many children.

To do so I would like each root to hold a reference list to it's children. Additionally, each child will need some data supplied by it's root to it's constructor (or some other similarly early point in it's lifecycle).

However I have not found a way to generate a component object in ts code and then insert the reference to it in the template. Is there a way to tell angular "Here, this component object, insert this right here."?

--

So far I had in my root.component.ts

```
children: Child[] = [];
onCreateChild(): void {
  this.children.push(new Child());
}
```

and in the template

```
<div  *ngFor="let child of children" child>
</div>
```

which so far seemed to work.

However recent development and testing has shown that the child displayed is not actually the child the root holds a reference on, but a child that got auto generated. (Which in hindsight makes sense.)('child' was also the selector tag of ChildrenComponent, which was an oopsie I did not notice initially.)

I have also tried solving this via the ComponentFactory route, however there I run into the problem that it seems I cannot supply specific data to the child, aside from it being a very cumbersome and restricted design.

Comment: A "recursive component" generally the item has two `Inputs`:the elements and the index of recursion. see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305905/how-can-i-create-a-nested-recursive-table-that-can-drill-down-x-levels-in-angul/55315414#55315414). [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905207/angular-8-implementing-a-hierarchical-list-recursively-with-dynamic-expansion/61911633#61911633) has anothere.g. and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56376237/create-tree-view-with-horizontal-and-vertical-lines-showing-the-connectivity-usi/56381812#56381812)